# Add a array-based figure over an image with pyplot

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I am plotting a DICOM slice from a CT on which I want to draw a Region of Interest (ROI). The problem is that I didn't succeed into displaying this ROI over my background DICOM image yet. The idea is to finally draw a colored circle on my background DICOM image. 
Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ArrayDicom = np.ones((512, 512, 148))
plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3), dpi=300)
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
plt.axis('off')
plt.set_cmap(plt.gray())
x = np.arange(0, 512, 1)
y = np.arange(0, 512, 1)
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, np.flipud(ArrayDicom[:, :, 0]))  # ArrayDicom = Image 3D Array

nx, ny, nz = (512, 512, 148)
# Grid creation
x, y = np.ogrid[:nx, :ny]
# Mask creation
radius = 5
x_center, y_center = (2, 2)
contour = (x - x_center) ** 2 + (y - y_center) ** 2 == radius ** 2
mask_contour = np.zeros((nx, ny, nz))
mask_contour[:, :, 0][contour] = 1
ax = plt.gca()
ax.plot(mask_contour[:, :, 0], color='red')

plt.show()
```

I used this tutorial https://pyscience.wordpress.com/2014/09/08/dicom-in-python-importing-medical-image-data-into-numpy-with-pydicom-and-vtk/ to display my DICOM images.
I think I just miss a way of plotting my datas. I know I can use `plt.Circle` but I would like to deal with sphere instead of circle next.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't think one can answer this given the pieces of code you show here. Create a [mcve] of the issue, such that people are able to reproduce this and are hence able to help you.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I edited the code, is this better?

Comment: I can't run this code. Just by looking at it, there is nothing obvious that would make this fail. In case you want someone to find out what problem there is, you need to make your case reproducible. See [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I update it to code something you could run. I don't know if it will change something but this figure will next be displayed into a Tkinter window as a FigureCanvasTkAgg object

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread the question completely. So what you are doing is plotting the positions of the flattened array where a circle *would* be: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu0aM.png). There isn't actually any circle anywhere in the code. Maybe you should for a moment forget about DICOM images and Tkinter and make sure you understand numpy arrays and the `plot` function - or ask a question which reflects the actual problem.

Comment: I just tried but `contour = (x - x_center) ** 2 + (y - y_center) ** 2 == radius ** 2` then `mask_contour = np.zeros((nx, ny, nz))` and finally `mask_contour[:, :, 0][contour] = 1` allow me to have an array where the coords of the outline of the circle is equal 1 and the rest of the array is equal to 0. By the way, I know I have a problem understanding how plotting works when it become harder than just plotting an array

Comment: `plot` would expect two arguments `x`, `y`, `plot(x,y)`. Those should be the coordinates of the circle. You currently do not even have those coordinates anywhere in your code.

Comment: I think I can have the coordinates in arrays using something like `np.where(mask_contour==1)` no? Would it work then? I Aldo tried using `imshow()` which take arrays as an arguments but it didn't work

Comment: `imshow(mask_contour[:, :, 0])` works fine. `ax.plot(*np.where(contour) )` would work in the sense that you get a line through the points, but not in the order you probably would like to see.